# Why is the value 0 not being parsed but other numbers are?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a temperature converter for Celcius, Kelvin, Farenheit and have been stuck on this little problem. I'm using an event listener to track and parse my inputs and whenever I passed in any number, the conversions worked including 0. I have 3 input fields with 3 placeholder texts so if I wanted to convert a Celcius temperature, they would convert into the Kelvin and Farenheit. However, when I backspace and leave the input blank, the other two temperatures return NaN which I understand since the fields now don't have a value.

So now I wanted to fix this problem of leaving an input blank and to reset the placeholder texts back to what they were originally instead of showing NaN. I've tried doing if statements to catch this specific problem and it works just fine. Now I can convert numbers between the different temperatures and even backspacing would then reset the placeholder texts as well. Everything works but the number 0. As soon as I type in 0, it isn't getting parsed and nothing is happening.

```js
const celciusInput = document.querySelector("#celcius > input");
const fahrenheitInput = document.querySelector("#fahrenheit > input");
const kelvinInput = document.querySelector("#kelvin > input");

function celciusConverter() {
  const cTemp = parseFloat(celciusInput.value) || "";
  const fTemp = cTemp * (9 / 5) + 32;
  const kTemp = cTemp + 273.15;

  //condition if there is an empty string in the input, placeholder values would reset instead of returning NaN.
  if (cTemp == "") {
    fahrenheitInput.value = "";
    kelvinInput.value = "";
  } else {
    fahrenheitInput.value = Math.round(fTemp);
    kelvinInput.value = Math.round(kTemp);
  }
}

celciusInput.oninput = celciusConverter;
```

```html
<div id="celcius">celcius: <input></div>
<div id="fahrenheit">fahrenheit: <input></div>
<div id="kelvin">kelvin: <input></div>
```

I would have expected 0 to be parsed and then converted just like any other number. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: It would be great if you could post a [mcve]. Also have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Because `parseFloat("0") || ""` is `0 || "" ` is `""`. Don't use `||` to have a fallback for `NaN`, as it is a fallback for *all*  falsy values. Better just drop the fallback and explicitly test `isNaN(cTemp)` in your `if` condition.

Comment: [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values are a weird concept in JavaScript, I'd suggest reading up on how it all works.

Comment: You should also use strict comparison, i.e. `===`, because `0 == ""` is true in javascript since they are both "falsy" values.

Comment: @j08691 This seems like a sufficient example to me, the problem is entirely within the code provided.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery For completeness the HTML of the form should be included

Comment: @adisib while it's often good advice to use `===` instead of `==`, especially when dealing with falsy values, the reason the comparison returns `true` isn't that all falsy values compare as equal. For example `"" == undefined` is `false`. It happens because `""` becomes `0` when coerced to a number.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I will definitely read more into all of this. It makes much more sense to me now.

Comment: @j08691 I added a [mre] to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
const cTemp = parseFloat(celciusInput.value) || "";
```

The `||` operator returns its first operand if it's truthy, otherwise it returns the second opererand. If the user enters `0`, `parseFloat()` returns `0`, which is falsey, so `cTemp` is set to `""` rather than `0`.

You should check whether `parseFloat()` returns a valid number, not whether it's truthy.

```
let cTemp = parseFloat(celcisuInput.value);
…
if (isNaN(cTemp)) {
    fahrenheitInput.value = "";
    kelvinInput.value = "";
} else {
    fahrenheitInput.value = Math.round(fTemp);
    kelvinInput.value = Math.round(kTemp);
}
```

Example snippet:

```js
const celciusInput = document.querySelector("#celcius > input");
const fahrenheitInput = document.querySelector("#fahrenheit > input");
const kelvinInput = document.querySelector("#kelvin > input");


function celciusConverter() {
  const cTemp = parseFloat(celciusInput.value);
  const fTemp = cTemp * (9 / 5) + 32;
  const kTemp = cTemp + 273.15;

  if (isNaN(cTemp)) {
    fahrenheitInput.value = "";
    kelvinInput.value = "";
  } else {
    fahrenheitInput.value = Math.round(fTemp);
    kelvinInput.value = Math.round(kTemp);
  }
}

celciusInput.oninput = celciusConverter;
```

```html
<div id="celcius">celcius: <input></div>
<div id="fahrenheit">fahrenheit: <input></div>
<div id="kelvin">kelvin: <input></div>
```

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that is better. I was too narrowly focused on the one statement.

Comment: Took me some iterations of editing my comment above before realising this :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I definitely understand it more and will be reading into it.

Comment: @Barmar I added a snippet to demonstrate your answer.